# Verilog : Use of assign and always

Tags: binary, verilog

```
module circuit_1 (a, b, c);
input [1:0J a,b;
output [3:0J c;
assign c = a + b;
```

If input a = 2'b11 and input b = 2'b10,

what value would output c have ? Please give a descriptive answer.

Also kindly tell me functionality of assign and always. I am a bit confused.

Comment: This is more of a [Binary Mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Addition) question. Please read the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Addition) page then update the question with your proposed answer.

Comment: RE assign and always, the Q&A Format here does not lend itself well to additional questions. You can ask a new question but the answer will likely be check out the [LRM - Language Reference Manual - SystemVerilog 2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) Particularly section 10, Assignment statements starting on page 196.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
c = 4'b0101      // Output, implicitly a wire
```

"assign" is used for net type  declarations(Wire,Tri etc).Since wires change values according to the value driving them, whenever the operands on the RHS changes,the value is evaluated and assigned to LHS(simulating a wire)

always - is used for registers + combinational logic.
If it is always(@ posedge clk)- The event posedge clk triggers the always block and the logic inside the block is evaluated and assigned.

always @ (*) - If something in the RHS of the always block changes,that particular expression is evaluated and assigned.

Imagine assign as wires and always blocks as registers (For now) , as their behavior is same.

Comment: `always @*` is for `reg` types not registers, `assign` implies the same combinatorial logic as `always @*`. `always @(posedge clk)` implies flip-flops (registers).

Comment: My bad.. I knew it but failed to explain it

Comment: No problem, you can edit you answers to improve it if you wish.

Comment: @Morgan If `assign` implies the same combinational logic as `always @*` why do I have to use reg-variables for the always-block and wires for the assign? Why can't I use the wires for the always-block too?

Comment: @GURKE because that is not valid syntax. reg was intended to mean flip flop, but the combinatorial usage messed that up. Modern versions of verilog (ie SystemVerilog) you can use `logic` instead, for all uses except multi driven wires. 
I think this is a pretty good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33462996/97073
An external reference: 
https://blogs.mentor.com/verificationhorizons/blog/2013/05/03/wire-vs-reg/

Answer (score 0):

c = 0101, actually c[2:0] become 101 but extension of 0 takes place as c is a 4 bit data.