# What is the difference between reg and wire in a verilog module?

Tags: verilog, hdl

When are we supposed to use reg and when are we supposed to use wire in a verilog module?

I have also noticed sometimes that a output is declared again as a reg. E.g reg Q in a D flip flop. I have read this somewhere - "The target output of procedural assignment statements must be of reg data type."

What are procedural assignment statements?

I have thoroughly googled this but was not able to find a clear explanation.

Comment: Did you check this [link](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/31624/what-is-the-difference-between-reg-and-wire-after-synthesizing)

Comment: See my blog about wire versus reg: http://go.mentor.com/wire-vs-reg

Comment: The link from dave_59 is now status 500 but can be found at archive.org. Current endpoint: [What’s the deal with those wire’s and reg’s in Verilog](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506124104/https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/verificationhorizons/2013/05/03/wire-vs-reg/).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

***Wire:-***

Wires are used for connecting different elements. They can be treated as physical wires. They can be read or assigned. No values get stored in them. They need to be driven by either continuous assign statement or from a port of a module.

***Reg:-***

Contrary to their name, regs don't necessarily correspond to physical registers. They represent data storage elements in Verilog/SystemVerilog. They retain their value till next value is assigned to them (not through assign statement). They can be synthesized to FF, latch or combinatorial circuit. (They might not be synthesizable !!!)

Wires and Regs are present from Verilog timeframe. SystemVerilog added a new data type called logic to them. So the next question is what is this logic data type and how it is different from our good old wire/reg.

***Logic:-***

As we have seen, reg data type is bit mis-leading in Verilog. System Verilog's logic data type addition is to remove the above confusion. The idea behind is having a new data type called logic which at least doesn't give an impression that it is hardware synthesizable. Logic data type doesn't permit multiple drivers. It has a last assignment wins behavior in case of multiple assignments (which implies it has no hardware equivalence). Reg/Wire data types give X if multiple drivers try to drive them with different values. Logic data type simply assigns the last assignment value. The next difference between reg/wire and logic is that logic can be both driven by assign block, output of a port and inside a procedural block like this

```
  logic a;
    assign a = b ^ c;                   // wire style 
    always (c or d) a = c + d;          // reg style
    MyModule module(.out(a), .in(xyz)); // wire style
```

Comment: will using a reg instead of wire result in slower circuit?

Answer (score 25):

Procedural blocks refers to `always`, `always_ff`, `always_comb`, `always_latch`, `initial` etc. blocks. While procedural assignment statements refers to assigning values to reg, integer etc., **but not** wires(nets).

`wire` elements must be **continuously driven** by something, and cannot store a value. Henceforth, they are assigned values using **continuous assignment** statements.

`reg` can be used to create **registers** in procedural blocks. Thus, it can **store** some value.

`reg` elements **can** be used as output **within** an actual module **declaration**. But,`reg` elements **cannot** be connected to the output port of a module **instantiation**.

Thus, a *reg* can drive a *wire* as **RHS** of an `assign` statement. On the other way round, a *wire* can drive a *reg* in as **RHS** of a procedural block.

For clear idea about declaration of `reg` or `wire`, refer the image below:

[image]

So, whenever inferring to sequential logic, which stores/holds some value, declare that variable/port as `reg`. Here, `Q` is a `reg` **inside** a module, but while **instantiating** this module inside some other module, then this port must be connected to a `wire`.

Remember, `wire` can only infer to combinational logic, while `reg` can infer to either combinational or sequential logic.

Dave's blog is a good source for detailed information. For further information, refer to [synthesizing difference](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/31624/what-is-the-difference-between-reg-and-wire-after-synthesizing) and [Verilog wire-reg](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCIQFjABahUKEwip08_ptu7IAhWk2KYKHZxzDLo&url=http%3A%2F%2Finst.eecs.berkeley.edu%2F~cs150%2FDocuments%2FNets.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHCZtUCnDRe9shHwQMyI-NfkvixJA&sig2=wEjqUQ98UPTaIbopgVgrgw&bvm=bv.106379543,d.dGY&cad=rja) links.

Answer (score 0):

Simple difference between reg and wire  is, the reg is used in combinational or sequential circuit in verilog and wire is used in combinational circuit

> reg is used to store a value but wire is continuely driven some thing and wire is connected to outport when module initialization but reg is con not connected