# What is the difference between input and reg in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, hdl

I have a circuit whose truth value looks like this `A =BC+^C[(B and C) or (not C)]`

Here I give,

```
output A;
input B, C;
wire w1, w2;

and (w1, B, C);
not (w2, C);
or (A, w1, w2);
```

My question is why do we write input B, C; Can we write it as reg B, C;?

What exactly is the difference?.

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459048/what-is-the-difference-between-reg-and-wire-in-a-verilog-module

Comment: An input can **not** be a reg. An output can be a reg but not in your case as the and/not/or gates need wires. For the rest see @Mahi 's link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between reg and wire in a verilog module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459048/what-is-the-difference-between-reg-and-wire-in-a-verilog-module)

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing a complete example, but `input`s and `output`s are part of a hierarchical module declaration. `reg` is a data type associated with a signal. Typically one encapsulates your circuit in a module, and then you instantiate that module in a top-level module to provide stimulus and observe the outputs.

```
module circuit( output wire A;
                input wire B, C;
  wire w1, w2; // internal wires

  and (w1, B, C);
  not (w2, C);
  or (A, w1, w2);
endmodule
module top;
reg B,C; // these are different signals that get connected to the circuit wires
wire A;
circuit c(A,B,C);
initial begin
   B = 0; C = 0;
   ...
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

comparing `input` and `reg` is similar to comparing a keyboard to a verilog code. `input` defines a direction of a port. `reg` defines a data type.

However, every port has a data type associated with it. Default data type for an input/output port is `wire`. So `input B` is the same as `input wire B`.

Now, the right question is: *what would be a differnce between `wire` and `reg`*. 
`wire` is a data type for describing connection between module instances. Its main characteristic is that it should always be connected and cannot keep is state otherwise. `reg` can keep the state if not connected. There are multiple differences in usage which you can find in corresponding verilog tutorials.