# What is the difference between using a reg and assigning values in hardware?

Tags: verilog, fpga

I am programming on an FPGA and I am wondering what is the implications and differences between a reg and a wire with assignment value.

For example in verilog

```
reg A;
wire B;

always @ (posedge clock) begin
A = 1'b1;
end

assign B = 1'b1;
```

What is the main difference in hardware for A and B?

Edit: I have checked that registers use resources of the FPGA but if wiring assignment does not use registers, how are the values obtained?

Answer (score 0):

You asked a wrong question. It should have sounded like:

> what is the difference between `reg` and `wire`.

`reg` is a type of data which is supposed to keep its state between transactions. Data of type `reg` can be assigned a value in `always` blocks (which contain sequential programming code).

`wire` is an interconnect media and is intended to connect modules. It is state-less and is not supposed to keep the state and should always be driven. The way to drive them is called *continuous assighment* and is represented by the `assign` keyword. Wires cannot assign any value inside always blocks and require `assign`.

there is another good explanation here:
[What is the difference between reg and wire in a verilog module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459048/what-is-the-difference-between-reg-and-wire-in-a-verilog-module)