# Getting errors in output wave window on vivado

Tags: verilog, complex-numbers

I am new to verilog and working my way up on a small code for multiplying two fixed point complex numbers, and here is the top module and the testbench I have written for the same but the wave window shows all Z for my inputs, any help will be appreciated

```
        module complex(a,b,c,d,
        x,y,
        z);
        input  signed [15:0] a,b,c,d;
        
        output reg signed [31:0] x,y;
        output reg signed [63:0]z; //the size is doubled as it will be concatenated
        reg signed [31:0] ac,bd,ad,bc;
      
        
        initial begin
        
        ac=(a*c); 
        bd=(b*d);
        ad=(a*d);
        bc=(b*c);
        
        
        
        x=ac-bd; //real part of the complex number, real is stored in x reg
        y=ad+bc; // imaginary part of the complex number, imaginary is stored in y reg
        z={x,y}; // concatenation of real and imaginary, first 32 bits here are for real, of which 16 bits represent fraction, same concept for imaginary part
        
        end
        endmodule

   // TESTBENCH
   module complextb();
          reg signed [15:0] a,b,c,d;
          wire signed [31:0]x,y;
          wire signed [63:0] z; //the size is doubled as it will be concatenated
           complex DUT (.a(a),
     .b(b),
     .c(c),
     .d(d),
     .x(x),
     .y(y),
     .z(z));

     localparam SF= 2.0**-16.0;

     initial begin
     a=16'b01011000_01000000; 
     b=16'b00011001_01000000;
     c=16'b01011000_01000000;
     d=16'b00010100_01000000;

      #10

      $display("%f,%f", $itor(x*SF),$itor(y*SF));
      end
      endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

From the logic you have written, it seems you want a combinational logic (as there is no clock involved). In order to have this work, you need combinational assignments, [and in verilog it is better to write them outside of procedural blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459048/what-is-the-difference-between-reg-and-wire-in-a-verilog-module) (like your initial begin).

Please also note that `initial begin` [is not synthetizable unless particular use cases which depend on the vendor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/384222/is-the-initial-block-in-verilog-sythesizable).

So I fixed you code like this:

```
module cplx_mul(a,b,c,d,
        x,y,
        z);
        input  signed [15:0] a,b,c,d;
        
        output signed [31:0] x,y;
        output signed [63:0]z; //the size is doubled as it will be concatenated
        wire signed [31:0] ac,bd,ad,bc;
      
        
        
        assign ac = (a*c); 
        assign bd=(b*d);
        assign ad=(a*d);
        assign bc=(b*c);
        
        
        
        assign x=ac-bd; //real part of the complex number, real is stored in x reg
        assign y=ad+bc; // imaginary part of the complex number, imaginary is stored in y reg
        assign z={x,y}; // concatenation of real and imaginary, first 32 bits here are for real, of which 16 bits represent fraction, same concept for imaginary part

endmodule;
```

And I got the following waveforms:

[image]

Note that this logic will have a very long critical path, so it could be better to pipeline the intermediate results, using registers and a clock.

```
module cplx_mul(clk,rst,a,b,c,d,
        x,y,
        z);
        
        input  clk,rst;
        input  signed [15:0] a,b,c,d;
        
        output signed [31:0] x,y;
        output signed [63:0]z; //the size is doubled as it will be concatenated
        reg signed [31:0] ac,bd,ad,bc;
        reg signed [63:0] x_r,y_r;
      
        always @( posedge clk) 
        begin
          // Synchronous reset
          if (rst) begin 
             ac <= 0; 
             bd <= 0;
             ad <= 0;
             bc <= 0;
             
             x_r <=0;
             y_r <=0;
          end else begin 
             ac <= (a*c); 
             bd <= (b*d);
             ad <= (a*d);
             bc <= (b*c);
             
             x_r <=ac-bd;
             y_r <=ad+bc;
          end
        end 
        
        assign x = x_r;
        assign y = y_r;
        assign z={x,y}; // concatenation of real and imaginary, first 32 bits here are for real, of which 16 bits represent fraction, same concept for imaginary part
        
        
endmodule
```

And the new testbench with the clock

```
module cplx_mul_tb();
          reg signed [15:0] a,b,c,d;
          wire signed [31:0]x,y;
          wire signed [63:0] z; //the size is doubled as it will be concatenated
          reg clk,rst;
          
      cplx_mul DUT (
      .clk(clk),
      .rst(rst),
      .a(a),
     .b(b),
     .c(c),
     .d(d),
     .x(x),
     .y(y),
     .z(z));
     
    
     localparam SF= 2.0**-16.0;
     
     initial clk = 0;
     always #10 clk=~clk;

     initial begin
     
     rst = 1;

       
     $dumpfile("dump.vcd"); $dumpvars;
     a=16'b01011000_01000000; 
     b=16'b00011001_01000000;
     c=16'b01011000_01000000;
     d=16'b00010100_01000000;

    
     // Start simulation - End of reset
     #30
     rst = 0;
     
      #10
       
            a=16'b0; 
     b=16'b0;
     c=16'b0;
     d=16'b0;

      $display("%f,%f", $itor(x*SF),$itor(y*SF));
      end
      endmodule
```

Which give the same results, but pipelined:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this and optimising the code for me. Appreciate it